# need suggestion on C# coding (efficiency)

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

In my code I have a dropdown selection and upon selection from dropdown the code performs further processing and generates report/data.

Further, the entire program depends on data which is gathered from 3 different operation

```
Operation1: processing a text files of size of size > 6MB

Operation2: SQL Query to a DB (Query takes around 1 minute)

Operation 3: HTTP POST request to server (The main costliest part of the programe)
```

So, to make it efficient I am thinking to perform this operation only once and use the data for all the different selection from dropdown.

Question is how can I do so as below:

1. I can't put it in "page_load" event because every time page loads the operations will carry out
2. I can't put it inside "dropdownlist_selectedindexchanged" event because then it will be same as #1.
3. I thought of doing it in "page_load" as below

---

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!ispostback)
    {
        Operation1();
        Operation2();
        Operation3();
    }
}
```

This is fine; the operations gets performed only once and I can use the data throughout, but then my page will take time to load as the operations takes time.

Is there any other way I can achieve what I want? Please let me know.

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data set will not change, you probably could manage to do it once at `Application_Start()`.

Edit - something like this (typing from memory and away from VS, i do VB):

```
Protected void page_load(object sender, eventargs e)
{
    // the name can be anything
    if (!System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["data_cache_filled"])
    {
        // code to fill the cache.
        // ...

        //mark it as filled
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["data_cache_filled"] = "yes";
    }

}
```

Comment: @Rodrigo, correct me if I am wrong but I think putting it in Application_Start() will affect the entire aplication ... means if performing the 3 operations takes 3 minutes (say so) then application will take 3 minutes to load. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it would take 3 minutes to start, _just once_. Of course you would then cache the results, so you would not need to load them again (only once per HttpApplication);

Comment: @Rodrigo, Thanks a lot for your reply and this is great ... seems like what I was looking for but I see a disadvantage as well ... from MSDN link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx I found that "Application_Start()" will fire only once when first resource is requested from the server ... which also brings the point that ... even though someone is actually not trying to visit my page ... this operations will gets carried out uselessly (my page is small part of the entire web app where I will be plugging it).

Comment: Then you have to trigger the cache insertion in your page_load event. You can create a Session variable (something like "IsCacheFilled") to tell if the cache has been filled. Then on each Page_Load, you check this Session variable, and if it has been set, you do not load the data a second time. If it is cleared, it means it is the first access to your page, then you load it.

Comment: @Rodrigo, sorry for troubling you ... I may not be asking this but if you could provide a small code sample that would really help ... I am almost a newbie in C# :). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Cache it. Using the `CacheHelper` class [from here](http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2008/12/10/c-cache-helper-class/), you could do:

```
internal List<Employee> Operation1()
{
  List<Employee> employeeData;

  if (!CacheHelper.Get("employeeData", out employeeData))
  {
    employeeData = (from x in db.Employees select x).ToList(); // or whatever

    CacheHelper.Add(employeeData, "employeeData");
  }

  return employeeData;
}
```